# Rails, Omniauth for Slack: How to access Auth Hash Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, slack-api, slack

I am allowing Users to Sign Up to my Service using their Slack Account.

I integrated the Sign In with Slack via the [omniauth-slack gem](https://github.com/kmrshntr/omniauth-slack).

Now I've got problems accessing the email and other information.

This is how I am currently doing it:

```
def self.find_for_slack_oauth(auth)
    user = UserProvider.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user.nil?
        user.user
    else
        registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
        unless registered_user.nil?
            user_provider = UserProvider.new
            user_provider.provider = auth.provider
            user_provider.uid = auth.uid
            user_provider.user_id = registered_user.id
            user_provider.save!

            registered_user.name = auth.info.name if registered_user.name == nil
            registered_user.avatar = auth.info.image if registered_user.avatar == nil
            registered_user.slack_id = auth.extra.raw_info.user_identity if registered_user.slack_id == nil
            registered_user.slack_team_id = auth.extra.raw_info.team_identity if registered_user.slack_team_id == nil
            registered_user.slack_team_name = auth.info.team_name if registered_user.slack_team_name == nil
            registered_user.skip_confirmation!
            registered_user.save!

            registered_user
        else
            user = User.new
            user.name = auth.info.name
            user.email = auth.info.email
            user.avatar = auth.info.image
            user.slack_id = auth.extra.raw_info.user_identity
            user.slack_team_id = auth.extra.raw_info.team_identity
            user.slack_team_name = auth.info.team_name
            user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
            user.skip_confirmation!
            user.save!

            user_provider = UserProvider.new
            user_provider.provider = auth.provider
            user_provider.uid = auth.uid
            user_provider.user_id = user.id
            user_provider.save!

            user
        end
    end
end
```

But I get no information out of it. Devise complaints that I cannot create a User without an email which is not blank.

What is the auth hash, which contains the information?

**EDIT:**

I don't get any values via the Auth Hash.

Here is my initialization (`devise.rb`):

```
config.omniauth :slack, Settings.slack.id, Settings.slack.secret, scope: 'identity.basic,identity.email,identity.team,identity.avatar'
```

Why do I get nothing?

Comment: In your method, you have find_for_slack_oauth(auth) -- the `auth` part is the hash.  It's sent from the omniauth callbacks controller to the model to create or update a user.  If you want to know what is in it, then as the first line of that method call `raise auth.inspect` -- this will spit a ton of information to your browser or log in which you'll be able to see where the email field is stored.

Comment: Thank you for that snippet of code, that's what I was missing to understand the problem! Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Please remove the Slack token from this post. Posting real tokens here will compromise the security of your Slack team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that I was just using the wrong scope.

Instead of:

```
config.omniauth :slack, Settings.slack.id, Settings.slack.secret, scope: 'identity.basic,identity.email,identity.team,identity.avatar'
```

I should use:

```
config.omniauth :slack, Settings.slack.id, Settings.slack.secret, scope: 'team:read,users:read,identify'
```

I hope this helps someone!
The Slack documentation isn't really helpful on this.